# NullPointerException on Initialize for JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MainProgram.start(MainProgram.java:25)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application MainProgram
```

WorldViewer.java

```
public class WorldViewer {

@FXML
private ImageView worldView;

@FXML
private ImageView item;

public void Initialise() {
    Image first = new Image("1.jpg");
    Image second = new Image("2.jpg");
    worldView.setImage(first);
    item.setImage(second);
    //Image basket = new Image("basket.jpg");
    //basketView.setImage(basket);
}
}
```

MainProgram.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainProgram extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            String viewerFxml = "WorldViewer.fxml";
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane)fxmlLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource(viewerFxml).openStream());
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            stage.setScene(scene);

            WorldViewer viewer = (WorldViewer)fxmlLoader.getController();
            viewer.Initialise();

            stage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

JavaFXL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button id="drop" layoutX="534.0" layoutY="360.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="51.0" text="Drop" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.666666666666668" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="76.88888888888889" />
      <Button id="pickUp" layoutX="534.0" layoutY="360.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Pickup" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.666666666666686" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.888888888888914" />
      <Polygon id="forward" fill="#0084ff" layoutX="297.0" layoutY="380.94772889879005" points="-10.777801513671875, -20.333328247070312, 15.444427490234375, -20.333328247070312, 2.111114501953125, -56.78310775756836" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="39.385599348280266" />
      <Polygon id="rotateRight" fill="#0084ff" layoutX="323.0" layoutY="387.0" points="-10.777801513671875, -20.333328247070312, 13.777801513671875, -11.000030517578125, -10.777801513671875, 2.777740478515625" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.222259521484375" />
      <Polygon id="rotateLeft" fill="#0084ff" layoutX="295.0" layoutY="387.0" points="-10.777801513671875, -20.333328247070312, -36.111114501953125, -9.777801513671875, -10.777801513671875, 2.777740478515625" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.222259521484375" />
      <HBox id="inventory" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="334.0" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="150.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.888888888888886" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" />
      <ImageView id="item" fx:id="item" fitHeight="68.0" fitWidth="65.0" layoutX="491.0" layoutY="214.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <ImageView id="worldView" fx:id="worldView" fitHeight="324.0" fitWidth="600.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I have this nullpointerexception error. I'm pretty sure it's something to do with my Initialise() method in the WorldViewer.java because even the print statement doesn't trigger, but I have no clue what. These are all the files along with the images I have that are within the project folder.
Thanks
Edit: the line 25 error points to "viewer.Initialise();" in MainProgram.java
I have read several stackoverflow posts but none seemed to fix my issue

EDIT2: Fixed it, added fx:controller="WorldViewer" into my FXML. So, this isn't a duplicate question to the one that is linked

Comment: The stack trace ways the problem is in `MainProgram.start` at line `25`. What line is that?

Comment: @Slaw the line 25 error points to "viewer.Initialise();" in MainProgram.java

Comment: That means `viewer` is `null` which makes sense as your FXML file has no `fx:controller` attribute.

Comment: @Slaw oh then how can I fix this?